# Debugging To many rerenders error react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am experiencing an issue where these lines of code throwing `Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop` error. Can anyone please help me to find out what is causing this issue?

```
options = useSelector(state => {
        if(!props.disabled) {
            if(props.values) {
                return props.values
            } else if(props.dispatch) {
                dispatch({type: props.dispatch});
                return state[props.getFrom] ? state[props.getFrom] : []
            }
        } else {
            return [];
        }
    });
```

Basically the usecase here is, On component load, I want to call a dispatch where an api will get hit and result will be stored in redux store. Then that values I want to render in dropdown in the same component!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line probably causes the component to re render and cause an infinite loop: `dispatch({ type: props.dispatch });` maybe you should put that in an effect:

```
//do not change reference to returning empty array
//  this can cause the component to re render
const EMPTY = [];
const Component = ({ disabled, values, dispatch, getFrom }) => {
  //I assume dispatch does not change and is from
  //  connect or useDispatch
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!values && !disabled && dispatch) {
      dispatch({ type: dispatch });
    }
  }, [disabled, dispatch, values]);
  const options = useSelector((state) => {
    if (!disabled && values) {
      return values;
    }
    if(!disabled && state[getFrom]){
      return state[getFrom];
    }
    else {
      return EMPTY;
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: How to retrieve state value in useSelector?

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding something. But in options, If values are not there, I want to get values from state. How can I do that. So in else is this the r8 way? return state[props.getFrom] ?

Comment: Unfortunately It is not working. The componet call is simple: ```{stepDetails.inputs.map(input => {
                    let Component = input.type;
                    return <Component {...input} />
                  })```

Comment: and input will be json format like this:

{
                    label: "abc",
                    field: "abc",
                    id: "abc",
                    disabled: false,
                    type: AutoCompleteInput,
                    dispatchAction: ABC_Action,
                    getFrom: "abc"
                }

Comment: Yes. It will be static

Comment: @user11823877 Where does props.values come from, is that static? You can check root reducer (console.log or debugger) to see if it keeps dispatching, do a console.log in the parent to see if that keeps re rendering and a console.log in the effect to see if that keeps getting triggered.

Comment: @user11823877 You are using map but don't give each component a [key prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) probably unrelated but you need to give it a key.

Comment: Yeah. I will give it. So the scenario for values is like this. If the component has static values, We will add values in input object and if the values of the components need to be derived from api we will add dispatch action in that will we get values from from api and add it in store which then will be used by component

Comment: Hey thank you! the issue was different. I was referencing wrong redux store location! Found that out.